# Jackson Deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I use this JSON deserializer:

```
scheduleContainerTypeInString = jp.getText();
```

and I use the deserializer like this:

[image: Usage of deserializer]

and at deserializer only **{** is in variable at **final String scheduleContainerTypeInString = jp.getText();**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image: Frontend to Backend object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "value" of the containerType property is a *json object*, not a simple value.  the json parser is positioned at the beginning of the containerType value, which is a "{" character (indicating the beginning of a json object).  you will need to consume the various events which encompass the json object which is the containerType value.  (e.g. loop through the object properties, handling the "value" property appropriately, ending when you get to the closing "}").

Comment: thanks! this helped me still a lot. Do you have another hint how to iterate through the properties? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3318489 - jackcson is a very popular framework, there are lots of tutorials online...